# How can I create a rule that will format a cell in Excel relative to the value of another cell in the same row?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a workbook that will be used daily, and I want to create a rule that will apply to all the whole workboook as new data is added

If the value of column E equals the value of column D within the same row, I want it to be green

If the value of column E does not equal the value of column D within the same row, I want it to be green

I can't seem to figure out how to apply a formula that will only work relative to another value within the same row.

Comment: You want to be green for both condition equal or not equal? Then simply use `=Or($E1=$D1, $E1<>$D1)`.

Comment: You've said if E = D then green as well as if E<>D then green.  That will just make everything green.  What @Harun24HR has said would work, but as I said, the result will always be True.  That aside, the $E1=$D1 is a mixture of absolute and relative reference.  The $E means it will always use column E, the '1' by itself, makes it relative to the row the formula is in.